# split a window without a split bar

Tags: c++, winapi, split, panel, childwindow

In order to split a window into 2, for example, viewing 2 documents at the same time, we created 2 child windows and a split bar to resize the child windows.

But I have seen many applications which have multiple panels without a split bar. In fact, there is a 'line' between the panels, but I found that they created an extra child window `hwndChild1Container` which contains the first child window `hwndChild1` and the size is a litte wider than `hwndChild1`, hence there is a `bar` as we see.

My question is: In order to do the same thing, I don't know which window style I have to use for `hwndChild1Container`. I don't want `hwndChild1Container` has a board like the main window, but I need it being resizeable and when the mouse is over the right boarder, the cursor changes the shape like the case for main window. Is there a build-in window style for such child window, or I have to do this manually in the window procedure of `hwndChild1Container`?

Comment: Does it need any special style? just make it slightly wider than its child as you suggested,

Comment: Another approach is to use just the windows you already have, a parent container containing some child windows, you actually don't need any additional windows: if the child windows are sized so that there's a gap between them such that the parent/container window is visible 'behind' them, then that parent/container can act as the bar. The parent container window can then draw its background appropriately and handle the WM_SETCURSOR messages and mouse clicks to get the right behavior, resizing the child windows as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Container does not need any special styles. Just process `WM_NCHITTEST` for container and return `HTBOTTOM` for bottom pixels.